# Fire a local function from inside an imported module in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run a local function, but I want to fire it from inside an imported module. This would be a sketch of how it should work... Any suggestions?

index.js

```
import { runBar } from "myModule.js";

runBar();

function foo() {
    console.log('foo should run whenever bar is executed');
}
```

myModule.js

```
export function runBar(){
   bar();
}

function bar() {
    console.log("bar is running...");
    //I want to call foo from here...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about passing `foo` as a parameter?

index.js

```
import { runBar } from "myModule.js";

runBar(foo);

function foo() {
    console.log('foo should run whenever bar is executed');
}
```

myModule.js

```
export function runBar(foo){
   bar(foo);
}

function bar(foo) {
    console.log("bar is running...");
    //I want to call foo from here...
    foo();
}
```

Comment: You also need to pass it from `runBar` to `bar`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder nice catch!

Comment: This is exactly how you should do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `foo` from `bar`, because `foo` isn't in scope.

To run `foo`, your options are:

1. Pass it to `runBar` and have `runBar` pass it to `bar`; or
2. Export `foo` and have `myModule.js` import it (cyclic dependencies are okay); or
3. Make `foo` a global (`globalThis.foo = function foo() {/*...*/}`, or possibly with `window` instead of `globalThis`), but I **don't** recommend doing that.